# django objects.filter(x__in = y) where y is repetitive QuerySet

Tags: django, filter, unique, django-queryset, one-to-many

```
Customer.objects.filter(customer_id__in=contact_list_senders)
```

contact_list_senders is a repetitive QuerySet that involves some customer_ids:

> {sender_id1, sender_id2, sender_id1, sender_id2, sender_id1}

When I try to find the Customer objects from the contact_list_senders QuerySet with the above code

Actual Output:

> {Customer1, Customer2}

Desired Output

> {Customer1, Customer2, Customer1, Customer2, Customer1}

I understand the actual output makes sense because there are only 2 Customer objects that matches with these contacts. Can you please help me to get the desired outcome?

models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=False, null=False)
    enrollment_method = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=False)
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0000.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    reserved_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0000.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Looks like you have to do a loop with list_sender, then combine the results into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start, but you'll have to do the rest in python:

```
customers = {x.customer_id: x for x in Customer.objects.filter(customer_id__in=contact_list_senders)}
final_customer_list = [customers[x] for x in contact_list_senders]
```

This first builds a dictionary mapping customer IDs to customers (without a database query for every one), and then uses that to build the final list, including duplicates.

It is assuming that your first list is a list of customer IDs, but can easily be adapted if not.

Comment: great solution without needing multiple queries. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any primary index on your table, I suppose the customer_id field should be one. In that case if you have the two models with a many-to-one relationship (many senders can relate to one customer) the models should look something like that:

```
class Sender(models.Model):
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
  # .. and the other fields od a sender

class Customer(models.Model):
  customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
  # .. and the other fields of a customer
```

And then a queryset:

```
# Replace all() with filter(your_params)
sender_list = Sender.objects.select_related('customer').all()

your_desired_output = [sender.customer for sender in sender_list]
```

The **selected_related** method tells Django to follow the relationship and get the related customer objects in the same query (to avoid running separate queries for every sender when iterating over the queryset). In most databases it would mean a single select with a left join of customers so it would be pretty effective.

I believe it would be the right way to do it in Django. If there's a reason you don't use primary keys and/or you cannot make such a relationship between models then you need to try a solution sent by user6731765 or try a raw query.

Comment: thanks for valuable input, senders and receivers are both Customer objects and there is a Contact table that has all the relations between all customers(like a chat application, relations being the chat rooms). I guess I could change the Contact table a bit to fit this method but it will effect a lot of code, so won't be able to use this method for now. But learned something new thanks!